# htaccess by adding index.php in the root of the site

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1EE772B8EBDDECBA378B575830E7E1B3\.txt$
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|wmt|google1f91ad48697ced36\.html|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com.br$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
Options -Indexes
```

In the first block lines it redirects the http to https;
In the second block it allows some direct access and removes the index.php

In the third block it adds the www if it does not exist.

The ultimate goal is to have urls like:

https://www.domain.com.br ou 
https://www.domain.com.br/foo/bar

The problem is that when the user enters the address
Domain.com.br (without www and without the http, only in the root of the site) it redirects to:

https://www.domain.com.br/**index.php**

Only at the root of the site does it add this index.php

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

I accept htaccess optimization suggestions as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these refactored rules:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/1EE772B8EBDDECBA378B575830E7E1B3\.txt$
RewriteCond $0 !^(index\.php|assets|wmt|google1f91ad48697ced36\.html|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Test it after completely clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tested your suggestion and apache returns 500. Something is wrong :/

Comment: Ah! I had a typo. It is fixed now. Can you retry.

Comment: Perfect! You are a genius :)